# How to play long sound like Skype incoming call in Android?

Tags: android

How to play long sound like Skype incoming call in Android?

I want to play default ringtone of my incoming calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RingTone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE));

ringtone.play()
```